# Multiple webpack configs, single react library chunk

Tags: reactjs, webpack, microservices

I've been looking into applying microservices concepts into the front end. One of the big benefits I'm looking to achieve is independently deployable UI components/pages with my React app. I'm looking at taking a Composite Frontend approach like in this [article](http://blog.xebia.com/the-monolithic-frontend-in-the-microservices-architecture/).

Our app would likely have multiple webpack configs, one for each of the main pages/components. I want to be able to use a single React lib chunk across each of our pages. Here's an example of two possible webpack configs:

```
// Page 1 component
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        Page1: 'Page1.js',
        React: ['react', 'react-dom']
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style!css'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('React', 'bundle.react.js')
    ]
}

// Page 2 component
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        Page2a: 'Page2a.js',
        Page2b: 'Page2b.js',
        React: ['react', 'react-dom']
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style!css'
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('React', 'bundle.react.js')
    ]
}
```

Is this possible to reference the same common chunk across different webpack configs?